# Android-SQLite. One to many relation

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, one-to-many

My question is about working with sqlite and android.

I have this app which will record locations, and for each location the user will be able to add photos.

I have table for

`locations(loc_id INTEGER, longitude REAL ,latitude REAL)`

which works perfectly fine. But I need to create second one which is photos. The photos table will hold the path name of the photo as a `TEXT`. It must also have another field which refers to a specific location through the `loc_id` as a foreign key. The thing is I do not know how to link up those two.

Any help greatly appreciated thanks !

Comment: You want to know how to make a foreign key relation in sqlite? Try here: http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE locations(
  loc_id INTTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  longitude REAL,
  latitude REAL
);

CREATE TABLE photos(
  photo_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  path TEXT, 
  fk_location INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY(fk_location) REFERENCES locations(loc_id)
);
```